# Thread status after calling notify

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I have a thread Thread1 is in waiting thread list by calling wait() on objectA, now another thread call notify() or notifyAll() on objectA, or interrupt() on Thread1, what's the status of Thread1? Is it runnable, or is it blocked?

Comment: Blocked on what exactly? Where specified? It is runnable until it encounters another blocking operation. Not a real question.

Answer (score 1):

If a thread is waiting then it is in a `WAIT` state.  Once the thread is notified either by calling `notify()` or `notifyAll()` on the object that thread is waiting on, the thread moves into the `BLOCKED` state waiting to get the `synchronized` lock.  Once it gets the lock then it can move into the `RUNNING` state.  It moves into the `BLOCKED` state because the notifying thread definitely has the `synchronized` lock already and other threads may also be blocked on the same lock.

If it is interrupted while still in the `wait()` method then the same thing happens.  The thread must first get the `synchronized` lock by sitting in the `BLOCKED` queue.  As soon as it gets the lock and enters the `RUNNING` state, it throws the `InterruptedException`.

You can see that with the following test program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized (foo) {
                    foo.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // this thread won't get here until main thread releases lock
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    synchronized (foo) {
        thread.interrupt();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be runnable. Plus it might be in running state already if your processor is not busy .
refer this http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_wait_notify.shtml for more example.

Comment: The state has nothing to do with the processor.  Also it is more complicated then that.  See my answer.

Comment: AniketGode and Gray are both more or less correct. The thread immediately becomes runnable, in which case it tries to reacquire the object lock (re-enter the synchronized section) and may become blocked on doing so.

Comment: @xagyg Sounds sensible, but do you have any proof for that from the specification or the bytecode?